# Express.js Json Display Format

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express

I am getting json data from mongodb and display it using res.json(data). The result looks like following human readable format.

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary"
                 }
}
```

Is there a way I can display this in raw Json without blank spaces and put them in one line? For example,
    {"glossary":{"title":"example".....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that very surprising (that it's rendering it that way). You might try `res.send(JSON.stringify(data))`. By default, `JSON.stringify` doesn't do any formatting.

Gratuitous `JSON.stringify` example:

```js
var data = {
  "glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary"
  }
};
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```